# starting apachectl from bash

Tags: linux, apache, bash

I am writing a bash file. I need to start *`apachectl`* from my bash file. so i wrote:

```
apachectl start
```

When I run it with root, an error occurred:

```
apachectl: command not found
```

I searched and I found that, I should be *super user* with `su -` not `su`

Now, I want to know:

- why this error occurred?
- How could i run it with `su`?

Comment: It looks like `apachectl` is not in your path. Try `find / -name apachectl`.

Comment: yes thanks, it was in /usr/sbin/, So Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The command not found error is because "apachectl" is not in your path. Simply use the full path of the command, e.g.

> /etc/init.d/apachectl start

If you get a permission denied error, then you need to run as a different user. That is a different problem though.

Answer (score 19):

In shell scripts you should use full paths in order to execute command unless directory with executable already in $PATH.
For instance, find where apachectl binary is located:

```
which apachectl
```

or

```
whereis apachectl
```

and you will get something like:

```
/usr/local/sbin/apachectl
```

So, use that.

Answer (score 5):

Use the find command to first locate apachecetl

```
find / -name apachectl
```

Then you can test it by running the status command (assuming this is the location from the find command)

```
/usr/local/sbin/apachectl status
```

Then you may need to restart apache if there's an issue

```
/usr/local/apache/bin/apachectl restart
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that the command `apachectl` is not in your environments path. Locate the directory, where `apachectl` resides and add this to your `PATH` or start it with the full path. Most modern distributions use `sudo` to allow users gain elevated rights, so you should use `sudo`, if available to you.

Answer (score 1):

Below command worked for me:

sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl  -kstart

Answer (score 1):

The answer above helped me a lot but the commands should be:

```
sudo netstat -tanp
sudo ss -tanp 'sport = 80'
sudo apt-get remove lighttpd
sudo <path>/apachectl -kstart
```

Answer (score 0):

First kill all httpd service using...

```
sudo killall -9 httpd
```

Second, find apachectl. Press ctrl+r into terminal enter a "apachectl" word To find the path of "apachectl".

After select:

```
sudo <path>/apachectl stop|start
```

Comment: After start apache sudo service httpd start

Answer (score 0):

This question is old but comes up in Google, so for future readers: Please notice on some distributions such as Debian **it is a sudo-only command** and trying to run it without sudo leads to the error: *command not found*. So in order to run it simply use sudo. Also if you want to know where the binary is located at too, the simplest way I recommend (if using APT) is:

```
$ dpkg -L apache2 | grep apachectl
/usr/sbin/apachectl
/usr/share/man/man8/apachectl.8.gz
```

As you see, it's under `sbin` which means is exclusive to admins space.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. You may run the following command first:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/sbin
```

Then use `apachectl restart` or etc.

Answer (score -1):

well, it happens why you port be used now other service. for you know that

service is use write next comand of netstat:

- sudo netstat -tanp.

if you wanna to know of port 8080 use next comand:

- trong textsudo ss -ntlp 'sport = 80'.

in my case was run lighttpd so apply next comand:

- sudo apt-get remove lighttpd.

Comment: please improve the grammar, the explanation is not very clear.